Why am I getting the error that `msys-2.0.dll was not found' when it *is* installed?
Whenever I try to run git in anywhere but git bash, I get the below error: git.exe - System Error || The code execution cannot proceed because msys-2.0.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
I have tried reinstalling git, restarting my pc, and removing msys-2.0.dll from C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin and reinstalling - nothing.
What's wrong, and what's the fix?

What does where git (or which git) say?

C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe C:\Users\ryr42\devkitPro\msys2\usr\bin\git.exe C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
(/mingw64/bin/git)

Let's get specific.  How exactly are you running Git when it fails?  What is the value of your PATH environment variable?  What is the full path to the Git executable you are running and the full path to the msys-2.0.dll you are expecting it to find?

@DavidGrayson Any command pulls the error, even one as simple as git version. I'm not sure what the "value" of my Path would be. The address to my git-cmd.exe's folder is C:\Program Files\Git, and the address of msys-2.0.dll is probably C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin, although there are 5 instances of msys-2.0.dll on my PC.

Problem still happening - any ideas?
